# "&" causes: pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: Specified workspace either does not exist or the user does not have permission to access that workspace

Tags: php, python, rally, pyral

I'm using pyral to connect to our Rally instance, and I keep running into this error with two specific Workspaces.

An AJAX call is made to a PHP function, which calls:
`exec('/usr/bin/python query.py --rallyWorkspace="'.$data['workspace'].'" --rallyProject="'.$data['project'].'" 2>&1')`

The problem is: if there is an ampersand in the Workspace Name, pyral shoots back the error that it doesn't exist.

I've tried escaping the ampersand with slashes and replacing it with `&amp;` but that doesn't work.

Is there any workaround for this from my end, or do I need to change the name of the Workspaces themselves?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [pyral](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyral) , 1.3.2 supports such characters in the Workspace name.